# Web application backend as a service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

We are building "The next generation" web site from the start.
at the moment for UI we use EXT and asp.net
we are thinking that the backend should be a wcf service hosted by iis in which the app will get the data from the service. the main reason is to support diffrent tech in the need of changing the UI. my worry is about speed. 
please i will thank any input.
Guy

Comment: You shoud use a service like iknode > http://iknode.com my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is the main concern, you can take 2 approaches:

1. Use a JSON based library. If its a simple app without much of logic at UI tier (and most pushed to service), you can make you pages pure HTML with JS support with using libraries like jQuery or EXT as you have already mentioned. The backend service can be a .NET or Java service as all support json natively.
2. If you are bound to use ASP.NET for multiple considerations, prefer tcp bindings over http bindings (read more about its pros and cons at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx). If security is not a big concern, dont use HTTPS or any transport level security.

Ultimately the implementation will depend a lot of the resources you have. If you have folks who are good in JS, then go for the first option. If folks are more comfortable with ASP.NET stick with the 2nd one.

Comment: thank you, we think of support ui from different platforms. but the web site speed is my worry. if its on the same machine what will be faster? by the way we use ext for ui, so json is probably the reasonable way to transfer data

Comment: having the service and client will be faster but it will add extra load on the hardware and will create a single point of failure. both the above points gain importance if your application is big - for small applications it works just fine

Comment: Yes , ext has extensive support for JSON.

Comment: and for big applications (our portal) is it good ?

Comment: Yes it will be good. I have used it in one of our applications and it works flawless

Comment: Ndo you mean the EXT ? i meant the architecture

Comment: The Architecture at a high level is good. For example this site (StackOverflow) work on a similar theme. The devil is in the details, how you design your services, how you deploy them, how well you handle it in javascript, the network latencies and host of other factors , and last but not the least which is the most crucial part - how you handle the DB operations and caching at service layer

Comment: nice answer, i liked it very much it was to the point thank you. can you recommend a good article for that material ?

Comment: You can read about StackOverflow's architecture at http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/8/5/stack-overflow-architecture.html .. Architecture's for other high volume and popular sites like facebook, linkedin are also available on the same site

Answer (score 1):

Speed depends upon the 'type' of binding used. 
[WCF Binding Decision](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/03/31/wcf-binding-decision.aspx)

Here is a general article on WCF Performance: [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I will take for granted that you will have multiple UIs and that you need WCF service for that. What is important from then on: are service and the web app on same machine / local to each other? If not, and if this is high traffic site, you will have performance problems here, and multiply those problems for every time you have to go to service to fetch data for single web page request (so try to merge this data fetching to single DTO objects or something).

The web site with remote backend is really rare I think, except if local and with low latency in between

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any specific worries rather than just 'speed in general'? Tell us more about how people will use the services, the type of data you'll be transmitting, are all the users local? or in separate countries? etc.

You're right that creating services / an API will allow you to swap out the UI or have multiple UI channels (browser, phone, tablet, etc, etc).

Speed is always going to be the compromise here. Your data has to be serialised to be made ready for sending over the service, however the biggest bottleneck will be the network transfer (presumably over HTTP).

You should look into caching (check out a product called Squid as a starting point) along with HTTP compression, and essentially just making sure that you make the server-side data retrieval code as efficient as possible.

Ta
Chris.